# Is * * * * * ? a valid Cron Job?

Tags: validation, cron, quartz-scheduler

I am talking about the [Quartz scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) having 6 values viz seconds,minutes,hours,day-of-month,month and day-of-week. The optional 7th field year is skipped. In that case, is this a valid cronjob? Is it supposed to run every second from initiated?

Second part of question: Is there any Cron validator available online? I have found some, but they are based on Linux Cron Jobs. I was looking for a Quartz Cron validator (Which is having an additional `seconds` parameter compared to Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every second use * * * * * ?.

You can validate using Quartz CronExpression API. Just write a small Test using this method:

```
org.quartz.CronExpression.isValidExpression(value);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I believe for every seconds the query must be `0/1 * * * * ?`. Then what could be the possible outcome of  `* * * * * ?`

Comment: Two exprssions same result.
"* * * * *  ?" == every-second every-minute  every-hour every-day every-month every-year. 

The ‘/’ character can be used to specify increments to values. For example, if you put ‘0/15’ in the Minutes field it means ‘every 15th minute of the hour, starting at minute zero.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html